# How can I arrange (different) squares in a grid correctly?

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

My standard layout (minimum width 1024px) has 4 rows. The first and the last one has 6 squares and in the middle there are two combined squares. But the first square in the third row is missing. I didn't make it with different CSS settings. I have tried `clear: both` or `float:left` etc.

Here you can see the hole, result screen needs to be min width 1024px:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwsh8ov0/

Haven't done any configurations for smaller screens yet.

Comment: This doesn't show anything in my browser (Safari 8.0.5)

Comment: That's because `height:auto` on empty divs means that they have no height and so are not visible.

Comment: @Gasim http://jsfiddle.net/fwsh8ov0/4/ should work with IE and Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve won't work with floating containers, due to the nature of `float`. A `float:left;` means that the container is shifted as far left as possible, or if there isn't enough horizontal space it is shifted down as far as it is necessary and then to the left.

In your case there are these two huge squares in the middle. After these the first square is placed to the right of them, but the second needs to be shifted down because it's lacking horizontal space. After the downshift, it still can't be shifted to the left, because there is still the huge square in the middle...

To achieve what you want, you could use html `table` with `colspan` and `rowspan`, or you could use absolute positioning of the containers, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but if you are trying to have four rows explicitly, then maybe you should define a row object. Something like the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="square half"></div>
   <div class="square half"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="square half"></div>
   <div class="square half"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
   <div class="square quarter"></div>
</div>
```

And for styling of the `row` element, you can either use `display:block;` with `float:left` or `display:inline-block` for the child; or `display:table` with `display: table-cell` for the child. The latter would be much easier to achieve as you don't need to worry about clearing floats or removing whitespace between inlines. Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqdgfd9u/2/

EDIT: If you don't want to use "row object", you can achieve the same using `inline-block` or `float:left`. Here is a fiddle with `display: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/mpq6cp7j/. It wouldn't be as neat but again, I don't really know what you are trying to do to make this post more specific.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with what I wanted to achieve and my solution respectively http://jsfiddle.net/as54tkq4/